# Irregular-Spaced Linear Index

Tags: matlab, indexing, sequence, vectorization, fill

I am trying to create a linear vector to be used as an index.  I need to fill numbers 1:99 between these starting numbers in the index x =  700, 1000, 1100, 2100, 2300, 2400, 2900.  I have tried using loops of various kinds and i'm not able to save each 100 number sequence in an array inside the loop.  I'd love to learn how to not use a loop and do this simpler.

So xfinal should look like - 700, 701, 702...799, 1000, 1001, 1002...1099, 1100, 1101, 1102,...1199, 2100, 2101, 2102,...2199, 2300, 2301, 2302,...2399, 2400, 2401, 2402,...2499, 2900, 2901, 2902,...2999.
I'm banging my head on the keyboard - thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's save the *keyboard* and *scary* loops with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
x = [700, 1000, 1100, 2100, 2300, 2400, 2900];
offset_arr = 0:99;
xfinal = reshape(bsxfun(@plus,x,offset_arr.'),1,[])
```

Comment: @excaza I would say, it takes time! ;)

Comment: Amazing.  Can you be so kind to explain "@plus", the "1" before the closed brackets and the meaning of the closed brackets?

Comment: maybe it's all related to the bsxfun function?  thanks again!

Comment: @user2100039 Yeah, the basic idea is to feed a row vector and a column vector to `bsxfun` for broadcasting. Now `@plus` is the operation to be performed with those two inputs. So, basically we add this offset_array across all starting points and thus we end with a 2D output. The final step is to have a row vector, i.e one column, so that's why that `1` with the `reshaping`. If you break down the code into two steps :  `bsxfun(@plus,x,offset_arr.')` and then the full code and watch the outputs, it would hopefully become clearer. Give it a try! :)

Comment: @user2100039 Typo: I meant *one row* and not *one column* there.

Answer (score 2):

A less compact, probably less efficient, slightly scarier to the keyboard version without a scary loop:

```
x = [700, 1000, 1100, 2100, 2300, 2400, 2900];
intermediate = 0:99;

tmp = repmat(intermediate, length(x), 1) + repmat(x.', 1, length(intermediate));
x_new = reshape(tmp.', 1, []);
```

Comment: Just scarier to my hands maybe to type out all that :D

Comment: @Divakar I made a [keyboard saving version for you](https://gist.github.com/sco1/e7e362946b7d7013ee095434ae308255)

Comment: Yeah that's a relief, especially with `intermediate` becoming `im`! ;)